# Image Converted From varbinary data shows blank images looks like picture 1 below

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

This is the Page which displays the converted image
[image: This is the Page which displays the converted image.]

This is the data of my table for binary image data ScreenPic
[image: this is the data of my table for binary image data ScreenPic.]

please help..
let me know what is the issue in getting images from database.
code for converting binary to image logic.:

```
namespace OverHR.Common
{
    public class Common
    {
        public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] ba)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ba);
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }


    }
}
```

code for displaying images from database:

```
@model List<OverHR.DAL.ScreenLog>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Pic</th>

    </tr>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {           
            var image=@item.ScreenPic;

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="@OverHR.Common.Common.byteArrayToImage(image.ToArray())" width="320" height="240">
                </td>       
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

logic for getting image from the database:

```
public List<ScreenLog> GetScreen()
{
    using (OverSeasHRDbDataContext ctx1 = new OverSeasHRDbDataContext())
    {
        var lstScr = ctx1.ScreenLogs.Where(p => p.AttendanceId == 193).ToList();
        return lstScr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Either the image byte data is corrupt, the `Image.FromStream()` method doesn't support the type of image file, or there's a problem with the loading of the image.

Comment: What is actually inside the img src= field if you look at the source? Because, I'm not too familiar with it, but this looks like you're dumping the raw data in there.

Comment: No Image data is not corrupted, I have used it in other project

Comment: in the img src i have called the method of my class common to convert the byte data to image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have searched for it and i find the solution that there are lots of images in database table and getting it by query take so much time so image can not get data from database and get time out, so for the solution i use linq query to get only 10 images and it worked for me....